# need to change jQuery to vue expand collapse code

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am new in vue js, need to change some jquery code to vue js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Add minus icon for collapse element which is open by default
        $(".collapse.show").each(function(){
            $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").addClass("fa-minus").removeClass("fa-plus");
        });
        
        // Toggle plus minus icon on show hide of collapse element
        $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        });
    });
```

can anyone help me or teach me, how can I solve this.

Comment: Try to share a reproducible example.

Comment: can you show the HTML as well? seems it's not related to Vue.js

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite a jQuery function like so.
I used it to overwrite slideToggle to a simple show/hide for QUnit test performance.

```js
$.fn._slideToggle = $.fn.slideToggle;

$.fn.slideToggle = function(){
    // new code here
    if (this.css('display') === 'none') {
        // applies jQuery show() to this
        $.fn.show.apply(this);
    } else {
        // applies jQuery hide() to this
        $.fn.hide.apply(this);
    }
};
```